# show that two equation are the same in differentiation

Tags: calculus

If $y=(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})^2$, show that $\frac{dy}{dx} =$ $\dfrac{2y}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

Then we have let $ u=(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$
$$
\frac{dy}{du} = 2(x\sqrt{x^2+1})$$ and $\qquad \frac{du}{dx} =\sqrt{x^2} \quad then\quad x.
$
however I can't show that $\frac{dy}{dx} =$ $\dfrac{2y}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's your u ?

Comment: Yes, I am assuming that you missed out $u$. (Is it that $u=x\sqrt{x^2+1} ~?$) Either ways, why don't you use chain rule, to differentiate $y$ straight-away?

Comment: can u plz give me the chain rule formula? thx

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=chain+rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y'=2(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})'$$

$$y'=2(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})\left(1+\frac{1}{2\cdot \sqrt{x^2+1}}\cdot (x^2+1)'\right)$$

$$y'=2(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}{ \sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)$$

$$y'=2\cdot \frac{\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)^2}{ \sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

$$y'=\frac{2\cdot y}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

Comment: very close but should be  $\dfrac{2y}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

Comment: @SbSangpi isn't it ?

Comment: Can u plz write the chain rule formula, so that I can use next time. thx

Comment: @SbSangpi [Chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)